# Eclipse keystroke to view codan message

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, what keystroke will show the codan message for a RSL e.g.

[image]

(obtained with mouse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit **<kbd>F2</kbd>** (*Show Tooltip Description*) to display the error message without using the mouse.